# How would you animate this spotlight animation in HTML5?

Tags: html, jquery-animate

I'm looking for ideas on the simplest way to recreate the following simple mouse-following spotlight animation found in http://www.themill.sg/index_main.html with a HTML5 animation.

Care to share some ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS, I formed a trapezium, and binding to the mousemove event, I get the x-offset of which then I adjust the width of border-left and border-right.

As the offset grows, I had to do a rotate and then a relative/left adjustment to make sure the point stays at the same spot.

You can see the final product at http://mill.unifide.sg

Cheers!